# Does the dispertion medium affects Quantum Dots fluorescence efficiency?

Tags: solutions

I would like to use CdTe Quantum Dots to make a fluorescent coating on a transparent support. There's a link to the material here: http://www.plasmachem.com/shop/en/62--cdte-quantum-dots-powder-hydrophilic-water-soluble

I observed that the fluorescence of these QDs is much higher when they are dispersed in water than when they are dispersed in a dry layer of acrylic.

Wondering why this happens, and being a very bad chemist/physicist myself, I was wondering if this loss of fluorescence was due to some physico-chemical interaction between the media (acrylic) and the QDs.

Does the interaction between the media and the surface of QDs affects in some way the luminescence mechanism of QDs? Or is it more a problem of structure, e.g. the QDs are "clustered" in the thin layer of dry acrylic while they are distant from each other in water?

Another simpler way of saying all that would be: what is the best media to make a fluorescent QDs coating? (I was thinking of acrylic or epoxy resin...)

(I also posted this question on the physics StackExchange)